# Why does Node.js crash with "abort: Invalid bytecode"

Tags: node.js, webstorm

This happens with Node.js v8.11.2  on Windows-10.

I'm debugging my Node.js program on WebStorm.
At some point I halt with the 'debugger' statement:

```
....  
ok (50) ;
debugger
ok (sCount);
```

When I step over ok (sCount) it
crashes with **"abort: Invalid bytecode"**.

There seems to be nothing wrong or peculiar 
about the call to "ok (sCount)" because I can
copy "ok (sCount)" to WebStorm inspector
where it works and gives the expected result.
I can also single-step INTO it.

IF I DON"T SINGLE-STEP but click "continue"
there is no crash.

If I single-step INTO 'ok (sCount)' I see it 
executing:

```
if (aBoolean)
{ return true;
}
```

The crash happens when I single-step over the 
statement "return true;"

Why does Node.js execute invalid byte-codes?
How to get around this problem?
How to make sure it can not happen in production?

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Have you tried using a newer version of Node.js?

Comment: > Have you tried using a newer version of Node.js?   Will do. Thanks

Comment: I am facing the same issue..Will the newer version of node worked for you ?

Comment: I don't suffer from this problem currently, I'm running v10.11.0. Don't recall exactly how I got around the original problem maybe I just stopped trying to debug the code-section where it happened.